# How to show and get AES key to/from user in C# WinFroms

Tags: c#, winforms, encryption, aes

Im working in Windows Forms, and Im working on an app that will allow you to encrypt / decrypt your string using AES, but I've a problem. How Could I show AES key to user? If he will encrypt string, he need AES key to decrypt it. I'm converting the key byte array, into string to show it to user in TextBox, but idk how to get this key from TextBox to decrypt string, because it is in string, not a byte array :/ (If you didn't know what im talking about bcs my English is bad, just ask in comment xD)

That's how i encrypt my string, and decrypt

````cs
static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV) {
            // Check arguments.
            if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
            if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");
            byte[] encrypted;

            // Create an Aes object
            // with the specified key and IV.

            using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create()) {
                aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                aesAlg.KeySize = 128;
                aesAlg.BlockSize = 128;
                aesAlg.FeedbackSize = 128;
                aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
                aesAlg.Key = Key;
                aesAlg.IV = IV;

                // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                // Create the streams used for encryption.
                using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream()) {
                    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)) {
                        using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt)) {
                            //Write all data to the stream.
                            swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                        }
                        encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }

            // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
            return encrypted;
        }

        static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV) {
            // Check arguments.
            if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
            if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");

            // Declare the string used to hold
            // the decrypted text.
            string plaintext = null;

            // Create an Aes object
            // with the specified key and IV.
            using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create()) {
                aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                aesAlg.KeySize = 128;
                aesAlg.BlockSize = 128;
                aesAlg.FeedbackSize = 128;
                aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
                aesAlg.Key = Key;
                aesAlg.IV = IV;

                // Create a decryptor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                // Create the streams used for decryption.
                using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText)) {
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)) {
                        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt)) {

                            // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                            // and place them in a string.
                            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return plaintext;
        }```
````

Comment: If this is about representing the binary key as a string, you should use a binary-to-text encoding like Hex or Base64.

Comment: Base64 is my second option to crypt/decrypt and its working

But in first option i need to get normal AES key, show it to user, and allow user to enter it to decrypt string, i will look on Hex.

What I need to do:
input > AES |
input > AES in base64 (working) |
AES > text |
AES in base64 > text (working)

Comment: _i need to get normal AES key, show it to user_: An AES key _generally_ consists of arbitrary binary data that cannot be decoded with a charset encoding like Utf8 (this would corrupt the data). Hex is often used instead, e.g. [cryptii](https://cryptii.com/pipes/aes-encryption).

Comment: I just convert AES key into HEX, to show it to user, and if user input encrypted text, and key in HEX, program will convert this HEX key back into byte array, Thanks for your help :D

Comment: Yeah, that's the ticket. Of course you may not have the user handle cryptographic keys at all, but that's another story.